# Why is .dropna() removing all values from my data?

Tags: python

When I run this code it empties my dataframe! For some reason when I uncomment the commands at the end of the code then the code works as I want! Can someone help?

```
#Import the Pandas library and Numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Your DataFrame
movies = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Lord of the Rings', 'When Harry Met Sally', 'Matrix', 'Taken', 'Sleepless in Seattle', 'Crank'],
'genre': ['Fantasy', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi', 'Action', 'Romance','Action'],
'actor': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
'length':[3.5, 2, 1.45, 2, 1.5, np.NaN],
'rating': [4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4]})

print("Print Original Movies")
print(movies); print("\n")

# movies = movies.drop("actor", axis=1); print("\n")
# print(movies); print("\n")

movies = movies.dropna()
print(movies)
```

Comment: Due to the column `actor` each row contains a `NaN`. And `dropna()` drops all rows that contain a `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropna()` will drop any row with a an NaN value. In your case, actors has an NaN on every row, so every row and column will be dropped.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might just want to delete actors with:

```py
del df['actors']
```

Answer (score 1):

because [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with no arguments is droping rows contains any column which is na...
u can drop either row or column... not single item , [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the default input args of [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) (axis=0 and how='any'), all rows where at least one value is NaN will be removed. Given that your "actor" column has only NaN, all rows will be removed. So dropping the actor column, "solves" your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO Mel, as *adir abargil* has mentioned by default the method `dropna()` removes all the rows with any missing element.

This behaviour is controlled by the `axis` argument. If `axis = 0`, all rows with at least one missing element will be removed. In your example the column **actor** is made entirely of missing values hence the whole dataframe will be dropped. If instead you want to remove all columns with at least one missing value use `movies.dropna(axis = 1)`.

Hope this answers your question! You can find more help by accessing the documentation of the method: `help(pd.DataFrame.dropna)`